# Pass cakephp form variables to javascript to display in confirmation message?

Tags: javascript, cakephp

How to Pass variables (test1, test2, test3...) of cakephp form to javascript function status(), to display all variables information in window.confirm("Display all variables here...").

Here is the code:

```
function status() {

             var status_id = document.getElementById("testId").innerHTML; 

            var keep = window.confirm("Display all variables here...");

            if(keep == true){

                return true;

            }else{

                return false;

            }
        }

</script>

<?php echo $form->create('Product', array('url' => '/myproducts/products/add/'.$product['Product']['id'] , 'onSubmit'=>'return status(this)'));?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo "Product Title";?></legend>

        <?php
            echo $form->input('test1', array('label' => __('Test 1', true)));
            echo $form->input('test2', array('label' => __('Test 2 ', true)));
            echo $form->input('test3', array('label' => __('Test 3', true)));

            echo $form->input('test_price', array('label' => __('Test Price?', true)));
            echo $form->input('testId', array('label' => __('Test ID',  true)));    

        ?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $form->end(__('Add Product >>', true));?>
```

Comment: Q1: What version of cake? Q2: Just to confirm, all you want to do here is display the 3 values entered for those test fields and submit the form if the user confirms (?)

Comment: cakephp version 1.2.6, yes just need to display the values that is entered in the field

Answer (score 0):

How about generating your string from the controller, sending it to the view, and just displaying it there?

**Controller**

```
$this->set('my_variables', "$test1, $test2, $test3");
```

**View**

```
var keep = window.confirm("Display all variables here: <?php echo $my_variables; ?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used cake 1.2 in a very long time, but I would assign ID's to all the DOM's at stake and rake it from there. The following should get you close to what you're after. **(jQuery Must be included for this example!)**

```
<?php echo $form->create('Product', array('url' => '/myproducts/product/add/'.$product['Product'['id'] , 'id'=>'form'));?>
<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo "Product Title";?></legend>

<?php
    echo $form->input('test1', array('label' => __('Test 1', true),'id' => 'test_1')); //assign ID's else they would be ProductTest1
    echo $form->input('test2', array('label' => __('Test 2 ', true),'id' => 'test_2'));
    echo $form->input('test3', array('label' => __('Test 3', true),'id' => 'test_3'));

    echo $form->input('test_price', array('label' => __('Test Price?', true)));
    echo $form->input('testId', array('label' => __('Test ID',  true)));

?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $form->end();?>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="" id ="submit_button">Submit</a>


<script>
    jQuery(function ($){
        $('#submit_button').click(function(){
            //gather the current values 
            var value_1 = $('#test_1').val();
            var value_2 = $('#test_2').val();
            var value_3 = $('#test_3').val();
            var display_text = 'Submit: '+ value_1 + ' ' + value_2 + ' ' +value_3 + '?';
            if(window.confirm(display_text)){
                //if confirmed, submit the form
                $('#form').submit();
            }else{
                //cancel logic here
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```